# Grouping objects inside nested javascript arrays

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, reactjs, object

I have the following array, which has an object holding nested arrays that in turn have objects of their own:

```
var list = [{
    one: [{key: 1, value: 'eng1'}, {key: 2, value: 'eng2'}],
    two: [{key: 1, value: 'esp1'}, {key: 2, value: 'esp2'}]
}];
```

I want to group the data above by the key property inside the objects of the nested arrays. The following is the desired structure:

```
var grouped = [
    {
        key: 1,
        group: {
            one: {
                value: 'eng1'
            },
            two: {
                value: 'esp1'
            }
        }
    },
    {
        key: 2,
        group: {
            one: {
                value: 'eng2'
            },
            two: {
                value: 'esp2'
            }
        }
    }
]
```

I have tried so many ways to achieve the above structure but to no avail. I have tried using `reduce` but that was mainly applicable if the objects were not deeply nested. My problem is the fact that the arrays are nested inside the objects and the key is embedded in those objects. Your help would be greatly appreciated.

The requirement is to not use any library such as underscore or lodash. I have to get this working with plain JS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use multiple `forEach` loops because of your data structure and add to new array.

```js
var list = [{
    one: [{key: 1, value: 'eng1'}, {key: 2, value: 'eng2'}],
    two: [{key: 1, value: 'esp1'}, {key: 2, value: 'esp2'}]
}];

var grouped = [];
list.forEach(function(e) {
  Object.keys(e).forEach(function(k) {
    var that = this;
    e[k].forEach(function(a) {
      if(!that[a.key]) grouped.push(that[a.key] = {key: a.key, group: {}})
      Object.assign(that[a.key].group, {[k]: {value: a.value}})
    })
  }, {})
})

console.log(grouped)
```

Comment: Thanks Nenad, I was hoping to avoid a nested loop. But, I guess, that is not possible.

Comment: Your nested data structure necessitates nested processes.  There are certainly other ways to do this, probably some involving `reduce`, but you won't get away from the nesting.

Comment: @pro Depending on your actual data structure maybe you can avoid first loop https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/2247/

Answer (score 1):

You may try for this:

```
var list = [{
    one: [{key: 1, value: 'eng1'}, {key: 2, value: 'eng2'}],
    two: [{key: 1, value: 'esp1'}, {key: 2, value: 'esp2'}]
}];

var grouped = [];
list.forEach(function(e) {
  Object.keys(e).forEach(function(k) {
    var that = this;
    e[k].forEach(function(a) {
      if(!that[a.key]) grouped.push(that[a.key] = {key: a.key, group: {}})
      Object.assign(that[a.key].group, {[k]: {value: a.value}})
    })
  }, {})
})

console.log(grouped)
```